# Sorting on Multiple fields mongo DB with mongooes. Does the order of field affect the query results?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a list document "Test" with format below:
{ _id: 1, **name**: 'Jony Tan', **age**: 10}     and  _id is index

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({}, { name: 1, age: 1}).sort({ name: 1, age: 1})
and
db.getCollection('Test').find({}, { name: 1, age: 1}).sort({ age: 1, name: 1})
```

Let me see the query results is the same (sort "**name**" first and "**age**" second).

So, how to use multiple sort with "**age**" first and "**name**" second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do multiple sort operation, like this,

- name first and age second

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({}, { name: 1, age: 1})
  .sort({name: 1})
  .sort({age: 1});
```

- age first and name second

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({}, { name: 1, age: 1})
  .sort({age: 1});
  .sort({name: 1})
```